# Angular directive/child directive transclude inside ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-transclude

The problem is that child directive binds to parent however syntax `{{name}}` gets ignored by `ng-repeat`. What would be the right way achieving this?

**HTML (Main/child directive)**

```
<compact-select
    no-item-selected-text="Add a Customer"
    no-item-selected-icon="fa-user"
    search-placeholder="Type a customer name"
    cs-model="customer"
    cs-items="contacts"
>
    <display-item-template>
        <span>{{name}}</span>
        or
        <span>{{item.name}}</span>
    </display-item-template>
</compact-select>
```

**Directive**

```
angular.module('core').directive('compactSelect', [function($timeout) {
    return {
        templateUrl : 'modules/core/views/components/compact-select-tpl.html',
        bindToController: true,
        transclude: true,
        scope: {
            noItemSelectedText: '@',
            noItemSelectedIcon: '@',
            csModel: '=',
            csItems: '=csItems'
        },
        controllerAs : 'ctrl',
        controller : function($scope) {

        }
    };
}]).directive('displayItemTemplate', function($timeout) {
    return {
        require: '^compactSelect',
        restrict: 'E'
    }
});
```

**Directive Template (modules/core/views/components/compact-select-tpl.html)**

```
<div class="compact-select-repeater-box" style="" >
    <div ng-transclude ng-repeat="item in ctrl.csItems | filter:searchParam" class="compact-select-repeater" ng-class="ctrl.getHighlightedClass(item)" ng-click="ctrl.itemSelected(item)">
        <span>{{item.name}}</span>
        <span>{{item.id}}</span>
    </div>
    <div style="position:absolute;bottom:0">
        <a href="#">+ Click here to add customer {{ctrl.message}}</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**I can see that**

```
<span>{{item.name}}</span>
<span>{{item.id}}</span>
```

**Gets replaced with**

```
<span></span>
or
<span>{{item.name}}</span>
```

**and not with**

```
<span>{{name}}</span>
or
<span>{{item.name}}</span>
```

**Question:** How do I get `ng-repeat` to respect html bindings syntax from child directive? Or is there is another way to achieve this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If i am not wrong, then you are trying to create a `list view` such that the `template` of the list would be provided by the user, but the methods (click,etc) would already be made available through the directive.

Now, since `angular 1.3`, the `transcluded scope` is a child of the `directive isolated scope`,

so, in your case, if you follow the correct hierarchy, you can access the `directive scope` from within the template provided by the user.

Here is your scope hierarchy:

`Directive isolated scope` --> `ng-repeat new scope for every row` --> `transcluded scope`.

so, if you want to access `directive scope` from the `transcluded scope`,
you would need to do `$parent` (for ng-repeat) and then access `item.name`, like below:

```
<display-item-template>            
       <span>Item Name: {{$parent.item.name}}</span>            
</display-item-template>
```

Also, you don't need the bindings inside your `compact-select-tpl`, because you want that content to come from transclusion:

```
<div class="compact-select-repeater-box" style="" >

    <div ng-transclude ng-repeat="item in ctrl.csItems | filter:searchParam" 
    class="compact-select-repeater" 
    ng-class="ctrl.getHighlightedClass(item)" 
    ng-click="ctrl.itemSelected(item)">
       <!--  <span>{{item.name}}</span>
        <span>{{item.id}}</span> -->
    </div>

    <div style="position:absolute;bottom:0">
        <a href="#">+ Click here to add customer {{ctrl.message}}</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: wow... this is awesome works well. Thanks for explaining directive scope life cycle.

Answer (score 2):

The `displayItemTemplate` directive that you transclude inside the other directive has already it's data interpolated `{{name}}` and `{{item.name}}`.

If you don't have these variables in the $scope, it will transclude empty strings inside your spans.

Then in your `compactSelect` directive, the div that gets transcluded will have it's content overridden.

If you move the `displayItemTemplate` directive inside the other directive's template, the repeat will work. (you will need to remove ng(transclude and transclude: true

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/5532/)

Additionally, if you use `bindToController`, don't put the attributes inside scope.

```js
function compactSelect() {
  return {
    template : [
      '<div class="compact-select-repeater-box" style="" >',
      '<div ng-repeat="item in ctrl.csItems | filter:searchParam" class="compact-select-repeater" ng-class="ctrl.getHighlightedClass(item)" ng-click="ctrl.itemSelected(item)">',
        '<display-item-template>',
            '<span>{{item.name}}</span>',
        '</display-item-template>',
      '</div>',
      '<div style="position:absolute;bottom:0">',
          '<a href="#">+ Click here to add customer {{ctrl.message}}</a></div></div>',
    ].join(''),
    bindToController: {
      noItemSelectedText: '@',
      noItemSelectedIcon: '@',
      csItems: '=csItems'
    },
    scope: {},
    controllerAs : 'ctrl',
    controller : function($scope) {

    }
  }
}
function displayItemTemplate() {
    return {
        require: '^compactSelect',
        restrict: 'E'
    }
}
function SuperController() {
 this.name = "a name";
 this.contacts = [{name:"rob"}, {name:"jules"}, {name:"blair"}];
}
angular.module('myApp', []);
angular
    .module('myApp')
    .controller('SuperController', SuperController)
    .directive('compactSelect', compactSelect)
    .directive('displayItemTemplate', displayItemTemplate);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="SuperController as s">
    <compact-select
        no-item-selected-text="Add a Customer"
        no-item-selected-icon="fa-user"
        search-placeholder="Type a customer name"
        cs-items="s.contacts">
    </compact-select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks I see where you going with this but thats not what I'm trying to achive.